# The handle OpenThread() had returned,QueueUserApc() thinks it is invalid

Tags: c++, c, windows

I would to use the function--QueueUserApc(),but it returns 0,and GetLastError() returns 6--invalid handle.There is only one handle--the second parameter of the function QueueUserApc(),but it was returned by OpenThread().so what's wrong there??????

part of the code:

```
void WINAPI My_IDtoHandle(IN PDWORD IDArray, 
                          IN DWORD dwNumber, 
                          OUT PHANDLE * Thread_Handle_Array)
{
    PHANDLE handlearray;
    DWORD count = 0;

    handlearray = (PHANDLE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 
                                     HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,  
                                     dwNumber*sizeof(HANDLE));
    for (; count < dwNumber; count++)
    {
        handlearray[count] = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, 
                                        FALSE, 
                                        IDArray[count]);
        if (handlearray[count] == NULL)
            printf("Open the thread-%d is failed!\n\n", IDArray[count]);
    }
    *Thread_Handle_Array = handlearray;
    return;
}
```

call the function above:

```
result = QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC)SetEvent, 
                      Thread_Handle_Array[count], 
                      (ULONG_PTR)(Target_Event_Handle_Array + count));
if (result == 0)
{
    printf("The inserting of the %dth function-SetEvent is failed!\n\n", count + 1);
    printf("The error code is %d\n\n", GetLastError());
}
```

And the handle the OpenThread returned is strang:

[image]

Comment: Are you opening threads of your own or remote process?

Comment: Why are `Number` and `dwNumber` separate arguments?  Can you post a [mcve]?  Have you checked in the debugger that the handle being passed to `QueueUserAPC` really is the handle returned from `OpenThread`?

Comment: @Ari0nhh remote process

Comment: @HarryJohnston yeah,i have debugged,there is no problem,They're the same。but i feel strange about the handle,it is very small,just like 183 or 164,like the picture above

Comment: Kernel handles are usually small numbers, so that's normal.  Other likely causes: some other code is closing the handles before the call to QueueUserAPC; the thread(s) in question have already exited; the thread(s) in question are the wrong bitness, i.e., attempting to queue an APC to a 64-bit thread from a 32-bit thread, or vice-versa.

Comment: oh yeah,I think I find the problem,thank you very much @HarryJohnston,it's the bitness,I had tried to queue an APC to 64-bit thread from a 32-bit thread,thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was attempting to queue an APC to a 64-bit thread from a 32-bit thread.

The documentation says:

> Similarly, if a 64-bit process queues an APC to a 32-bit process or vice versa, addresses will be incorrect and the target application will crash.

... which was apparently added in response to a bug report as described in [this USENET post](http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel.narkive.com/hP78sEka/queueuserapc-64-bit-to-32-bit) seven years ago.  At that time it seems that any such call to QueueUserAPC() would fail with `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` but would also crash the target thread.

It seems likely that this issue was later addressed by explicitly blocking any such attempt and reporting `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.